# How can I dismiss a bootstrap panel using data-dismiss?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I have a button which opens a panel and I want to be able to close it like I would with an alert.

The Default panel example from bootstrap docs

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

If I add a close button as documented for an alert to the panels header, the button removes the header only.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do this by using an undocument feature to set the target of the dismiss action...

```
<button type="button" class="close" 
data-target="#id_of_panel" 
data-dismiss="alert">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</button>
```

This will make the close button close the panel as opposed to its parent element.

Answer (score 3):

I used Bootstrap version 3 and fontAwesome.

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#id_panel" aria-expanded="true">
        <div class="panel-title">     
            <i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Formulario 
            <i class="fa fa-minus-square pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </a></div></div>
```

And your content div.

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="id_panel" aria-expanded="true">
...content
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to be a little clearer in answers, notably explain why you have that, for example why that solves issue raised in OP, not just share your code. stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer is a great guide

Answer (score 1):

Those who wants to place a "close" button inside the collapsible panel to collapse panel back, you can use following snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Collapsible Panel</h2>
    <p>Click on the collapsible panel to open and close it.</p>
    <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a>

          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
          <div class="panel-footer">
            <button type="button" data-target="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some time passed since this question was raised... and in the meantime the BS3 panels have been replaced in BS4 by the so called cards. A nice way to realize a dismissible card without any custom JavaScript and only with Bootstrap CSS classes is the following: the combination of `card-header`, [the Bootstrap 4 Close Icon](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/close-icon/) and [negative margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/#negative-margin) (here `.mt-n5`) on the `card-body`. The close icon gets nicely positioned within the card-header and the negative margins pull the card content closer into the header area.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="closeablecard" class="card card-hover-shadow mt-4">
    <div class="card-header bg-transparent border-bottom-0">
      <button data-dismiss="alert" data-target="#closeablecard" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body mt-n5">
      <h5 class="card-title">Your Title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem recusandae voluptate porro suscipit numquam distinctio ut. Qui vitae, ut non inventore necessitatibus quae doloribus rerum, quaerat commodi, nemo perferendis ab.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To actually close the card we can make use of the BS4 Data-API and put the the following data attributes in the button tag: `data-dismiss="alert" data-target="#closeablecard"`.
data-target is the ID of our card and data-dismiss=alert triggers the actual close event in Bootstrap.

[See a Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hennson/jbn5yfmp/)...

HTH,
hennson

Answer (score 0):

For other users who do not want to dismiss but show/hide, data-toggle="collapse" is the key. In below snippet, you can use one button to toggle the panel and panel itself has toggle button.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<html>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn-text" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#helpCollapsePanel">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"/> Click to Open
</button>
  <div class="collapse" id="helpCollapsePanel" style="width:250px;">
    <button type="button" class="close" style="margin-right: 5px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#helpCollapsePanel">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-body">Content Panel</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```