# Bootstrap close div box

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello everyone i started learning bootstrap for a while,

And i want to make close button for div boxes i have this code but the X button doesn't work:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color: lavender;">
                <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Share</button></th>
                <th><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="panel" aria-label="close" id="hide">&times;</a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Manchester United - Manchester United</td>
                <td>2 - 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FC Barcelona - Manchester</td>
                <td>T1 2+p.p</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Manchester United - Manchester United</td>
                <td>2 - 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FC Barcelona - Manchester United</td>
                <td>2 - 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: lightgreen;">
                <th>Bet: 2100</th>
                <th>Win: 55864</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("panel").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(".panel")` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `panel` element, you need `.panel`:

```
$(".panel").hide();
```

`panel` corresponds to `<panel></panel>` element, clearly you don't have in in your code.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set an Id to the div class="panel" and set this id in a href=#id. THen change data-dismiss="modal" to data-dismiss="panel" and you can remove the javascript code.

You can check it here
https://jsfiddle.net/foyckLaf/

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="current-pane">
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: lavender;">
            <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Share</button></th>
            <th><a href="#current-pane" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" id="hide">&times;</a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Manchester United - Manchester United</td>
            <td>2 - 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FC Barcelona - Manchester</td>
            <td>T1 2+p.p</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Manchester United - Manchester United</td>
            <td>2 - 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FC Barcelona - Manchester United</td>
            <td>2 - 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: lightgreen;">
            <th>Bet: 2100</th>
            <th>Win: 55864</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Related: [How can I dismiss a bootstrap panel using data-dismiss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367356/how-can-i-dismiss-a-bootstrap-panel-using-data-dismiss)