# Dismiss panel in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary copyright-wrap" id="copyright-wrap">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Copyright Info
            <button type="button" class="close"
                    data-target="copyright-wrap"
                    data-dismiss="panel">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            &copy; some random dude
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason it just doesn't work. Is a `panel` even dismissable? I found solutions for alerts and modals, but not for panels. Another person stated, that there is an undocumented feature ( [How can I dismiss a bootstrap panel using data-dismiss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367356/how-can-i-dismiss-a-bootstrap-panel-using-data-dismiss) )

But that didn't work either.

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q25ynxhs/1/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per [Relequestual's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367356), it seems you were missing the hashtag in the `target` parameter, and the `dismiss` parameter was suppose to stay set to `alert`.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/y9yroaee/

Answer (score 4):

Please use this sample Code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default fade in collapse" id="demo" >
<div class="panel-heading"> <a data-toggle="collapse"   href="#demo"  class="close" >&times </a>
</div><div class="panel-body"></div></div>
```